# Graph Theory Conjectures

Tags: graph-theory, big-list, computer-science

What are some important conjectures in graph theory that have been checked by computer up to order 11?

Comment: What do you have in mind when you say "important"? can you expand on your motivation

Comment: And also, it is often not really necessary to check all graphs, since often it can be proven that the smallest counter example for a conjecture would be a graph with a special structure (e.g. snarks are known to be the smallest counter example for some conjectures if there would be a counter example) and so many conjectures have been checked up to a much higher order than 11.

Comment: What about those that have been checked up to order 10? 
Seriously, a good community wiki might be "What are some conjectures of the form 'Every graph that has property X also has property Y', and how far have they been checked?", along with a couple of examples of what you have in mind. In general, the prospects of good answers increase if some effort is put into the question.

Answer (score 3):

> Graffiti (by S. Fajtlowicz) and Graffiti.pc (by E. DeLaViña) are computer programs that produce conjectures in graph theory.

See Doug West's web page, "[Some Conjectures of Graffiti.pc (2004-07)](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~west/regs/graffiti.html),"
and the more recent, "[Bibliography on Conjectures, Methods and Applications of Graffiti](http://cms.dt.uh.edu/faculty/delavinae/research/wowref.htm),"
which includes papers through 2011.

Answer (score 1):

I know one. The reconstruction conjecture of the undirected graph. That work is due to BD McKay.